# how to compare list of dict with each key in python?

Tags: python

```
list1 = [
    {'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},
    {'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'},
    {'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}
    ]

list2 =  [
    {'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},
    {'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'},
    {'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}
    ]
```

I have 2 such list of dict (ex) , I want to compare each key of both lists, means A of dict1 1st list with A of dict1 2nd list , A of dict2 of list1 to A of dict2 of list2
similarly I have to check all the keys, but my expected output is

`{'A':True , 'B':True , 'C':True}`  Means if all the A match with each other  from both the dict it will return true and even If one do not match it will written as false

( ex in dict2 of list 1 if value of say 'B' is 'bb' if that do not match with dict2 of list 2 then B will be false if all all other B are matching in other dict

Comment: IIUC, try: `{k:all(d1[k]==d2[k] for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2)) for k in list1[0]}`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the keys for all dicts from both lists, and then check the set of values are the same from each list using a dict comprehension.

```
keys = set(k for d in list1 + list2 for k in d.keys())
d_combined = {k:set(d[k] for d in list1) == set(d[k] for d in list2) for k in keys}
```

Ouput:

```
{'A': True, 'C': True, 'B': True}
```

But if the order of the elements in the two lists is important then this won't be sufficient.

Comment: Yes order of the keys is same, as in am trying to test the outputs which has to be same, like I have 7 keys in each dict and len(dict) varies but length will be same for both the lists, basically we are comparing same two outputs

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the keys of dict in both list So, try this code;

**Solution 1: (If order of keys is important):**

```
dct = {}
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    for k1,k2 in zip(l1.keys(),l2.keys()):
        if k1 == k2:
            if k1 in dct.keys():
                dct[k1] += 1
            else:
                dct[k1] = 1
for key,value in dct.items():
    if value != len(list1):
        dct[key] = False
    else:
        dct[key] = True
```

**Solution 2: (If order of keys is not important):**

```
dct = {}
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    for k1 in l1.keys():
        if k1 in l2.keys():
            if k1 in dct.keys():
                dct[k1] += 1
            else:
                dct[k1] = 1
for key,value in dct.items():
    if value != len(list1):
        dct[key] = False
    else:
        dct[key] = True
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thank you for the help, but solution 1 is always writing true even when results are different

Comment: I gave this as input... list1 = [{'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},{'A':'aa','BB':'bb','C':'cc'},{'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}]
list2 = [{'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},{'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'},{'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}]
& output... {'A': True, 'B': False, 'C': True}

Answer (score 0):

By using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [
    {'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},
    {'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'},
    {'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}
    ]

list2 =  [
    {'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},
    {'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'},
    {'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}
    ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list1)

output={}
for i in df1.columns:
    output[i] = df1[i].equals(df2[i])

        
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'A': True, 'B': True, 'C': True}
```